# Insufficient Authentication Scopes Error When Using gcloud CLI to Manage Google Cloud VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization

I have a situation with Google Cloud involving two virtual machines:

- instance1 (Windows Server 2022)
- instance2 (Windows Server 2019)

My goal is to manage instance2 from instance1 using the gcloud CLI, utilizing the service account XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. To achieve this, I'm attempting to run the following command in the CMD console within instance1:

```
gcloud compute instances describe instance2 --zone=my-zone --project=my-project
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Strangely, executing the same command on my local PC using the identical service account works without any problems.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, and can you provide any insights into what might be causing this "insufficient authentication scopes" error? I would appreciate any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you for your help!